# "provide" method for model, not for string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add meta keywords to `<head>` of website.

In `application.rb` I have:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<%= meta_tags(yield(:keywords)) %>">
```

In my `Point` model I have 7 cases (for Russian): nominative, genitive, dative, accusative, ablative, prepositional. All of them are strings and I want to use all of them in meta keywords. So, I need to `provide` not a string, but a model to use it like:

```
def meta_tags(point)
  if point.empty?
    'keyword, keyword, ... , keyword'
  else
    "keyword #{point.nominative}, keyword #{point.genitive}, ..."
  end
end
```

In `points/show.html.erb` I have:

```
<% provide(:keywords, @point) %>
```

But I receive an error:

```
undefined method `nominative' for "#&lt;Point:0x000001082964f0&gt;":ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer
```

So, rails take `@point` as a string, but not as object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yield :keywords` is returning a `String`. Try this:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<%= yield(:keywords) %>">
```

and this

```
<% provide(:keywords, meta_tags(@point)) %>
```